Did I pick Job's tears too early?
Our Job's tears have four colors of berry: truly green, kind of greeny-brown, deep dark purple, and spooky white-gray-purple (the oldest ones).
I just picked the purple and whitish ones. They came off the stems easily.
Online it says to pick when they are brown. None of them are brown! Will they maybe dry to brown? I am hoping eventually to crack the shells, extract the kernels, and cook like a pilaf. No interest in use for beads or tea.
